# How to do I link keyboard with a object in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm very new to Java and I am a noob at it. I am creating a basic game where you can cast a spell on a player, location or item. What I am trying to do at this moment is for the player to cast a spell on something using keyboard input which I have done to a certain degree. when I enter the number for the spell I want to cast it says "You have picked spell 1" but what I want it to say is "You have picked spell Fireball" (Spell 1 is the Fireball Spell". Here is my code for the function:

````
        for (Spell s: playerSpells) {
            System.out.println(playerSpells.indexOf(s)+1 + ". " + s); //prints out the player's personal spellbook, each numbered and you can pick which spell you want to cast
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { }
        }
        String keyboardInput  = (String) Utilities.getInput();
        int myInt = Integer.parseInt(keyboardInput);
        System.out.println("You have picked spell" +" "  + keyboardInput +p.getSpells());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 



    ```
````

Comment: What does `p.getSpells()` return?

Comment: Please clarify your question so that we have a greater understanding of your code and your problem. Note though that it is good practice to keep UI (user interface) code separate from program logic code (the "nouns" of your program).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it returns the player's personal spellbook

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't even have a ui tho

Comment: Wouldn't the spellbook be multiple spells then? You need to access the one you are actually picking - by index for example, and then getting that spell's name. We can't tell you how, if you don't show us, what `p.getSpells()` returns exactly.

Comment: Sam, yes you do. Your UI is the code that interacts with the console/keyboard. It's not a "GUI", but it is a UI. Keep that code out of your Spell and Player classes and in the main class or separate UI class.

Comment: @DennisB. the p.getSpells returns ```spells.SpellBook@232204a1``` which is just the description of the spellbook?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ah apologizes I'll change that

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp take a look at HashMap in Java. It might suit you better than ArrayList